# How can I avoid tag soup with MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I was reading this in my quest to justify MVC over non-mvc like regular old php (not using MVC, even classic asp could be used, albeit painfully):

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/07/web-development-as-tag-soup.html

And I can't find the answer.  I think it is inevitable to get tag soup.  Yes, I know MVC separates the model and controller, but when you get to the view, everything just goes hideous.  I can read emitted html just as good or better than tag soup.

I won't be using unit testing, so it's not that important an advantage.  I'm not sure how I can ever avoid an ugly view, now matter how I get it wither mvc or just emitting html.

I do not see it any easier to maintain a view with all the bizarre coding (and it is code) than using `response.write "<table>"`.

example:  [Dealing with ASP.NET MVC "tag soup"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248772/dealing-with-asp-net-mvc-tag-soup)

The answer by Arnis (no offense to him or anyone else), fixes the horrible code in the question, but to me that still looks bad or at least not what I expect.  To me those angle brackets might just as well have been `<% %>` or `<?php ?>`.

I like things like codeigniter and it's really the cleanest I've seen but it's still not what I expect.  I think I was hoping some magic was present in MVC that made everything beautiful.  Apparently, unless one is really really careful, there no better off than they were with classic asp, as it relates to a view.

This is mostly about the view.  Not about which language is better for what or who's template engine is the greatest (they all have the same markup mixup tendencies).

Believe me.  I **want** to make MVC work with my co-developers, so I'm not railing against it as a paradigm at all.  I can't get them to agree to something just because everyone's doing it or something like that.

Thanks for any comments.  I have to be able to justify these things, and while I understand MVC and what I am getting, the view makes a lot of it seem like a big waste of time.

edit:  Everything seems to be geared toward a particular framework instead of plan. I see some insight but in the end it seems there is no way other than discipline.  Thank you all for your answers.

Comment: A comment on your edit johnny - do you realise that the Razor view engine is included in MVC 3? No additional frameworks are required, so no need to convince your boss to buy or download any extras!

Comment: @connell My question was about more than asp.net and any scripting engine it has.  It was encompassing any MVC set up.  asp.net was merely an example.

Comment: ah, my apologies then. I misunderstood, but so did Marcin it would seem, who added the [tag:asp.net-mvc] tag ;D

Comment: @ConnellWatkins I thought most misunderstood.  They were all great answers but so tied to asp.net that it didn't help as well as I had hoped.  I think the final answer was, just be disciplined, and a few pointers on what not to do.  I did like the Razor solution, however.

Answer (score 19):

Have a look at using the [Razor](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx) view engine, which is included in **MVC 3**. Also try to keep all your logic in the *Controller* class and build a *Model* based on what is displayed in the *View*.

- **Razor** is one obvious way to avoid tag soup as there's no need for any `<%` and `%>` tags - simply an `@` before your code and the view engine works out where the C# ends and the HTML starts.

  ```
  <span class="name">@Model.Name</span>
  ```

  Even loops and if statements still look sexy in a `.cshtml` file with Razor and that magic `@` character.

  ```
  @if(shouldDisplayDiv) {
      <div id="mydiv">Div is displayed!</div>
  }


  @foreach(User user in Model.Friends) {
      <a href="@user.Url"><img src="@user.ImageUrl" title="@user.Name" /></a>
  }
  ```

  Razor also handles HTML encoding for you by default, so your view won't be full of `Html.Encode` calls. *(Note: if you need to output HTML, you can use the `Html.Raw` helper method).*
- **Putting your logic into the Controller** will ideally remove the need for large code blocks in the view. Try to get the model objects to contain all the dynamic data for the view, exactly as it will be displayed in the view. Aim to not have *any* C# code in your view at all (pointless, but if that's the target, see how close you can get to it!).
- **Partial views** can nicely separate different parts of your view (but try not to use them *too* much). You can also pass a different model object to each partial view, which I find can be handy for some large loops, or a little something like a [flair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair).
- **HTML Helpers** are also very useful *(thanks subkamran)*. There's a similar concept here to the partial views mentioned above, but HtmlHelpers are slightly different because you specify the method's parameters (and their types), as opposed to partial views which you may pass a single Model object. Here is a [good example of how to implement them](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2011/03/23/comparing-mvc-3-helpers-using-extension-methods-and-declarative-razor-helper.aspx). Again, these can look very neat in your `cshtml` code.

  ```
   <div class="specialdiv">@Html.SomeMethod(Model, "String", 5)</div>
  ```
- **Client-side MVC** is another option, and a strong suggestion if you are developing AJAX-heavy web applications. Following the *logic in the controller* you would use a client-side MVC framework like `Backbone.js` to template HTML in a tidy manner, and use jQuery `.ajax()` to talk back and forth with your controller. It's a great practice for separating your presentation layer, leaving you with some beautiful View markup!

I stick to these little guidelines and it works like a charm for me. Nice, clean HTML markup with the occasional `@` character. Very easy to maintain (well at least the Views are!).

***EDIT:*** Please note that all of these points are included in ASP.NET MVC 3 and are all 'best practices' are far as Microsoft are concerned. There is no need to install any extra frameworks, plugins or addons to stick to these guidelines.

Comment: Agreed; Razor makes me tingle all over. I've seen some complex Razor views and they're still good looking, depending on how well they were though out. Partial views make things a lot nicer, in addition to Razor Helpers (e.g. `App_Code\Helpers.cshtml` with `@helper` syntax).

Comment: HELPERS! Thank you, I've added those into the answer.

Comment: Thanks @one.beat.consumer for adding the Client-side bullet. I was going to put this in (or similar) but wasn't sure if it actually helped the **tag soup** problem at all. The way you explained it just about gets away with it! I've re-edited because your formatting got the indenting wrong for two of the sections :P Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

There is a reason why MVC is gaining traction.  While it's true that there are some tags added to the view, it is by far cleaner if the logic is correctly handled in the controller where it should belong.

It's also important to understand what MVC really is: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller.  The advantages that you get from it are cleaner separation and easy substitution.

Consider this.  You have a customer that wants you to write an application that supports both traditional browsers and mobile browsers.  With the MVC pattern, it's really easy to have the controller detect the platform and change the view that is rendered.  If done correctly, swapping out one view for another should be a very simple process.

I have 7 years of experience writing application in ASP.NET Forms.  Once I switched to MVC and begun to understand MVC, I realized I would never go back.  The views are cleaner, debugging is simpler and the logic is more obvious.  The last application I wrote uses MVC and jQuery, has 3000 users a day and has become the model site for which all our sites are now written.

Our customer asked us to add mobile support to our site.  Because we choose MVC in our implementation, it took us 1 week to add full support to mobile devices.  There is no way we could have done it that quickly and utilize the code so efficiently had we done it in ASP.NET Forms.

While the sample code from http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/07/web-development-as-tag-soup.html does look horrible, have you ever looked at an ASP.NET GridView?  The HTML is atrocious.  The sample you provided also shows someone who could do some work to clean up their views.  Here is a comparison of a gridview vs MVC with Razor:

GridView:

```
<asp:datagrid id="voucherGrid" runat="server" CssClass="dg" CellPadding="2" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyField="cx_nbr" 
        Width="800px" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" PageSize="20" OnPageIndexChanged="voucherGrid_PageIndexChanged" 
        OnSortCommand="voucherGrid_SortCommand" OnItemDataBound="voucherGrid_ItemDataBound">
        <SelectedItemStyle CssClass="dgSelectItem"></SelectedItemStyle>
        <AlternatingItemStyle CssClass="dgAlternateItem"></AlternatingItemStyle>
        <ItemStyle CssClass="dgNormalItem"></ItemStyle>
        <HeaderStyle ForeColor="White" CssClass="dgHeader"></HeaderStyle>

        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Image">
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:HyperLink id="voucherImageLink" Target="_blank" runat="server">Image</asp:HyperLink>                                               
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateColumn>
            <asp:BoundColumn DataField="cx_voucher_nbr" SortExpression="cx_voucher_nbr" HeaderText="Call #">
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:BoundColumn>
            <asp:BoundColumn DataField="cx_pkup_datetime" SortExpression="cx_pkup_datetime" HeaderText="Date" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}">
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:BoundColumn>
            <asp:BoundColumn DataField="cx_pass_name" SortExpression="cx_pass_name" HeaderText="Passenger">
                <ItemStyle Wrap="False"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:BoundColumn>
            <asp:BoundColumn DataField="cx_pkup_address" SortExpression="cx_pkup_address" HeaderText="Pick-Up">
                <ItemStyle Wrap="False"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:BoundColumn>
            <asp:BoundColumn DataField="cx_dest_address" SortExpression="cx_dest_address" HeaderText="Destination">
                <ItemStyle Wrap="False"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:BoundColumn>
            <asp:BoundColumn DataField="cx_trip_miles" SortExpression="cx_trip_miles" HeaderText="Miles" DataFormatString="{0:N2}">
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:BoundColumn>
            <asp:BoundColumn DataField="cx_pkup_datetime" SortExpression="cx_pkup_datetime" HeaderText="Time" DataFormatString="{0:t}">
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:BoundColumn>
            <asp:BoundColumn DataField="cx_vch_wait_time_amt" SortExpression="cx_vch_wait_time_amt" HeaderText="Wait" DataFormatString="{0:C}">
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:BoundColumn>
            <asp:BoundColumn DataField="cx_vch_other_amt" SortExpression="cx_vch_other_amt" HeaderText="Other" DataFormatString="{0:C}">
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:BoundColumn>
            <asp:BoundColumn DataField="cx_vch_admin_charge_amt" SortExpression="cx_vch_admin_charge_amt" HeaderText="Admin Charge" DataFormatString="{0:C}">
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:BoundColumn>
            <asp:BoundColumn DataField="cx_vch_fare_amt" SortExpression="cx_vch_fare_amt" HeaderText="Rate" DataFormatString="{0:C}">
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:BoundColumn>
        </Columns>

        <PagerStyle ForeColor="White" CssClass="dgPager" Mode="NumericPages"></PagerStyle>
    </asp:datagrid>
```

Razor:

```
<table id="voucherGrid" class="dg" style="width: 800px;">
   <th class="dgHeader">
      <td>Image</td>
      <td>Call #</td>
      <td>Date</td>
      <td>Passenger</td>
      <td>Pick-Up</td>
      <td>Destination</td>
      <td>Miles</td>
      <td>Time</td>
      <td>Wait</td>
      <td>Other</td>
      <td>Admin Charge</td>
      <td>Rate</td>
   </th>
   @foreach(var voucher in Model.Vouchers) {
   <tr>
      <td>@voucher.Image</td>
      <td>@voucher.CallNum</td>
      <td>@voucher.Date</td>
      <td>@voucher.Passenger</td>
      <td>@voucher.PickUp</td>
      <td>@voucher.Destination</td>
      <td>@voucher.Miles</td>
      <td>@voucher.Time</td>
      <td>@voucher.Wait</td>
      <td>@voucher.Other</td>
      <td>@voucher.AdminCharge</td>
      <td>@voucher.Rate</td>
   </tr>
   }
</table>
```

You tell me which looks easier to understand?  To me it's a lot cleaner to deal with html tags and a few extra @ or <% tags.

You also mentioned there being no need for unit testing.  I would reconsider that thought.  Unit testing can be tremendously useful in finding issues before they happen on a production site.

Answer (score 2):

There and back again. Again and again. Raw HTML. Dreamwearver. ASP. MS Word. ASP.NET,  MVC.NET. We seem to be able to hit either end of the spectrum but there is no sweet spot in the middle.

In the final analysis perhaps the most we can hope to say is "well, at least all the madness is isolated in the view." I say "hope" because from my experience it's a lot easier to say "object oriented" than to do object oriented with all the software principled goodness that OO implies.

In the long run tag soup is not the problem. It absolutely is not the problem in the context of MVC. Appalling coding is the problem. MVC parts, fused together like Siamese triplets, clearly demonstrating incompetence in software design and coding principles is by far the greater crime.

An MVC framework like Ruby on Rails or MVC.NET will help coding efficiency when coding in the MVC paradigm; it won't make you code faster per se. And it certainly will not prevent a code maintenance nightmare if you don't know what the hell you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use razr view engine (My preference, i think it looks neater). `response.write "<table>"` is easy enough to write.  But are you doing that in a file/class that ONLY controls the view and could be easily swapped or changed without touching any service logic?  That brings me to #2.
2. Discuss seperation of concerns with your group and decide where each piece of logic lives.  Where are the dependency touchpoints, is all your logic grouped up in DLL which have no knowledge of views/controllers?  Decide from the beggining and write it down somehwhere.
3. Keep views as views!
4. Don't do anything in a view!
5. Once you're at the view you are just viewing!
6. Have I mentioned that views are just that?

I don't begrudge anyone for using MVP or any other paradigm.  But if you want to try out MVC, do it right and you will find that refactoring and maintaining your code to be much easier.

my 2cents

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of a view layer over tag soup is that the view layer should isolate bad logic from bad data, making the root cause simpler to track down. This will not happen automatically, it has to be baked into the code constraints of the view. The best approach I've seen regarding HTML views using MVC is the following (from [Tony Marston](http://tonymarston.net/php-mysql/model-view-controller.html)):

- Code which transforms data into HTML is display logic.
- Code which creates or obtains the data which is subsequently transformed into HTML is not display logic.

Knowing is half the battle, consistent implementation is the other. With great power comes great responsibility, so using a limited subset of commands helps enforce cleaner code. The minimal statements would be print and include. Looping and data binding to generate tables, lists, or forms can be handled by JavaScript libraries or XSLT. Variable assignment, conditional logic, and string manipulation can be done in a local or global include. Anything else can be handled by the model or controller.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do any calculations in your template code.

Take a look at what is allowed in Django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/templates/

No arithmetic. No passing parameters to methods. No definitions of any sort (other than in loops). This forces you to do almost everything in the view methods, and pass in any objects and lists required, which keeps it clean.

Answer (score 1):

You can use GWT, ZK, Vaadin, JSF 2 or something that hides HTML. I don't know what you mean by MVC. Django/RoR/CakePHP Model-View-Presenter pattern sometimes called MVC or real MVC. If you stick to MVC you should have ONLY data binding and event triggers in your view code.

I think it is a design problem not technology.